# How do I prevent Netbeans from not being able to start Tomcat because the port is already used?

Tags: apache, tomcat, netbeans

I tend to get this annoying error alot using Netbeans 7.2. The that occassionally comes up is,

> Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8084 is already in use.

I'm part of a small group of developers and a couple of us have encountered this, and our solution is to go simply kill the Java process using it.

However, our boss insists that this isn't necessary and that my "Duct-tape solutions" are NOT adequate.

It's not a task given to me or anything, but it is annoying and I'm wondering if he's right.  Is there a permanent solution to this Apache Tomcat error?  Is there some way for me to configure Apache Tomcat so that this won't happen again?

## Update

That would also work, but I don't see how that's any better than me going in and killing the stupid process.  Your solution would only mean I have more than one instance of the same app server running.  But, what I wanted was a way to prevent the stupid Apache Tomcat instance from still staying up even though I wanted to kill it using the IDE.

Comment: Your boss doesn't know what he is talking about. Ask him what *his* solution is. You can't solve this problem from the NetBeans end, other than by using a different port. Not everything you don't understand is 'duct-tape', and even duct-tape is very useful, when you have a duct that needs taping. And there is nothing 'stupid' about another process using a port you need. There is far too much of this meaningless use of language in this discussion.

Answer (score 6):

Use a different port for the Tomcat. You can easily change the port number in net-beans by simply moving on to servers>tomcat and right click .. properties. and change the port to say 8083 etc...

Comment: I voted your answer up, but that also sounds like a duct-tape solution too.  :D.